# I sudo deleted /usr/lib/python & /usr/lib/python3

Tags: command-line, server, python

I know I shouldn't do that but I was pissed at pip not detecting my installation.

I know `apt` and `apt-get` didn't work properly now so `apt-get --fix-missing failed`

Is it possible to reinstall python with reinstalling ubuntu?

Comment: Please provide the exact command you tried and the output.

Comment: Did you try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure python python3`?

Comment: I find exercise (a nice 4km run) to be a better coping strategy for frustration. I'm sure that my loved ones and co-workers prefer it, too.

Comment: Most of the command do depends on python.. so most of them failed

`dpkg-query: package 'python' is not installed and no information is available
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: python is not installed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could download the deb files from [pkgs.org](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/), open it with an archive manager and unpack the folders `/usr/lib/python` and `/usr/lib/python3` from those files.

You need libpython and libpython-stdlib
For 64bit, python2.7 and ubuntu 18.04 this would be [libpython](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/libpython2.7_2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04_amd64.deb) and [libpython-stdlib](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/libpython2.7-stdlib_2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04_amd64.deb). For other versions you need to find the packages with [pkgs.org](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/) as said earlier.

The debs contain a file called `data.xz`. When installing, this file is unpacked. Go to usr/lib in that file. (In some archive managers ./usr/lib) From there you unpack the python folder to your /usr/lib and python should work again.

Comment: Thank you. Finally this got to something.. not completely fixed yet